# checkboxes for mysql select query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a query that uses checkboxes from an html form. I'm not sure if i should create an array but at the current time I am only getting results from one of the checkboxes.

Here is my checkbox setup.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Black">Black
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Blue">Blue
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Brown">Brown
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Green">Green
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Grey">Grey
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Orange">Orange
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Pink">Pink
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Purple">Purple
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Red">Red
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Teal">Teal
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="White">White
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Yellow">Yellow
```

here is my php and mysql query

```
extract($_GET);

$Color =  $color[];

$query = "SELECT * FROM tblYarn WHERE Color ='".$Color."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

I'm trying to select yarn by color and only getting one color at a time.

Here is my display table code

```
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "\t<tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
}
echo "<td><img src=./images/$col_value border='3' ></td>";


echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: i tried this without the brackets (color[]) and still only got one color displayed from the query

Comment: `$Color = $color[]`. No need for that. Just use `$color`, it's already been provided by `extract`.

Comment: you really really really shouldn't use extract(). you're trying to recreate the bad bad bad days of register_globals. don't be lazy.

Comment: i'm not trying to be lazy at all, i'm taking a php mysql course in college and this is what the professor gave us to work with. i guess he's old school and lazy

Comment: You should instead use `$color = $_GET['color']`. It's safer. Tell your professor this.

Comment: i agree and see how that would be better, that's extracting just the value of the form input for $color and not all the form input right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
extract($_GET);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tblYarn WHERE Color IN ('" . implode("','",$color) . "')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: actually i put all the brackets back into my checkboxes color[] and now your code works. thank you!!

Comment: would this also work if i wanted to query from two tables and get items from two different checkbox groups?